# .NET MAUI cuts off frame height after 40 units

Tags: xaml, height, frame, maui

I'm trying to render a frame in .NET MAUI. Here is my XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiUITestFrame.MainPage">
    
    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Frame BackgroundColor="Gray" HeightRequest="300" BorderColor="Green"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    
</ContentPage>
```

My problem is that the frame seems to be cut off after 40 Units, but only on Windows:
[image]

[image]

On Android, everything looks perfectly fine.

If I go below 40 units of height, it renders with the proper height, but it still looks cutoff (Border and rounded corners are missing on the bottom edge).

I don't know if I'm missing something really obvious, or if something is just broken, but I would be very happy if anyone could tell me what is going on here, and how I can fix it.

Comment: `Frame` is designed to enclose some content. Put any view *inside* the Frame. It'll probably resize to enclose it. OTOH, Frame is one of a handful of "legacy" controls from Xamarin Forms, that were not rewritten to use the new Maui rendering model. So there could be a bug with it. (`Border` is a newer Maui control for wrapping stuff.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue about this problem.

You can follow it up here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8438 .

Thank you so much for your feedback and patience.